# How to not overwrite dispatch with blank state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

**Background:**
I am practicing the idea of `React/Redux`. I would want to follow the flow of data. 
`axios` dispatches `action` -> reducer setState to `props` -> Component `render()`

The problem may be more than 1 point. Because I am new to `Frontend` world.
Please feel free to re-design my app(if needed)

**Problem:**
company does not render out because `this.props.companies` is blank. But `axios` does fetch the array from backend.

`action/index.js`

```
//First experiment action returns promise instance
export function fetchCompanies(token) {
  const jwtReady = 'JWT '.concat(token);
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': jwtReady
  };
  const instance = axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: `${ROOT_URL}/api/companies/`,
    headers: headers
  });
  return {
    type: FETCH_COMPANIES,
    payload: instance
  }
}

export function getCompanies(token){
  const jwtReady = 'JWT '.concat(token);
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': jwtReady
  };
  const instance = axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: `${ROOT_URL}/api/companies/`,
    headers: headers
  });
  return instance
    .then(data=> store.dispatch('GET_COMPANIES_SUCCESS', data));
}
```

`company_reducers.js`

```
import {FETCH_COMPANIES, GET_COMPANIES_ERROR, GET_COMPANIES_SUCCESS} from "../actions/const";


export default function (state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_COMPANIES_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        companies: action.payload
      };
    case GET_COMPANIES_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        err_msg: action.payload.text
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

`reducers/index.js`

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {reducer as formReducer} from 'redux-form';
import LoginReducer from './login_reducers';
import CompanyReducer from './company_reducers';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  login: LoginReducer,
  companies: CompanyReducer,
  form: formReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

`component/select_teams.js`

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {fetchCompanies, getCompanies} from "../actions";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

class SelectTeam extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    this.state = {
      token,
      companies: null,
      err_msg: null
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const tmp = this.props.getCompanies(this.state.token);
    tmp.then(res => {
        console.log(res)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  };

  renderErrors() {
    return (
      <div>{this.state.err_msg}</div>
    );
  }

  renderCompanies() {
    return _.map(this.props.companies, company => {
      return (
        <li className="list-group-item" key={company.id}>
          <Link to={`/${company.id}`}>
            {company.name}
          </Link>
        </li>
      )
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.companies === null) {
      return (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      );
    }
    console.log(this.props);

    return (
      <div>
        <h3>&#10084; Select Team &#10084;</h3>
        {this.renderErrors()}
        {this.renderCompanies()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {companies: state.companies}
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    fetchCompanies: fetchCompanies,
    getCompanies: getCompanies
  }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SelectTeam);
```

`App.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import SelectTeam from "./components/select_teams";
import reducers from './reducers/index';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import promise from "redux-promise";
import {applyMiddleware, createStore} from 'redux';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import LoginPage from './components/loginPage';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise)(createStore);

const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, isAuthorized, ...otherProps}) => (
  <Route
    {...otherProps}
    render={props => (
      isAuthorized() ? (<Component {...props} />) :
        (
          <Redirect to={
            {
              pathname: '/login',
              state: {from: props.location},
            }
          }
          />
        )
    )}
  />
);

function PageNotFound() {
  return (
    <div>404 Page Not Found</div>
  );
}

// TODO: I will add RESTful validation with backend later
function hasToken() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  const isAuthenticated = !((token === undefined) | (token === null));
  return isAuthenticated;
}

export const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);

class App extends Component {
  //I will add security logic with last known location later.
  //Get the features done first
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <Switch>
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/select-teams" isAuthorized={hasToken} component={SelectTeam}/>
              <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage}/>
              <Route component={PageNotFound}/>
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: First solution in my mind. It is not use `action` and try plain `callback` to do `setState`. But it it not the `React` flow I want.

Comment: You are not dispatching an action when you receive data from server

Comment: @ram1993 Your hint is right. I have to dispatch it. Right now I follow `Redux-Thunk`. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should dispatch an action with the data fetched from the server.
Actions are pure functions that return an object (the object has at minimum a TYPE field).
If you have any async operations, you may use [Redux-Thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk), which is an action creator that returns a function, and call the api fetch within it.

Here is the `actions` snippet:

```js
// imports..
export const fetchCompaniesSuccess = (data) => {
   retyrn {
      type: FETCH_COMPANIES_SUCCESS,
      data
   }
} 


export const fetchCompanies = (token) => dispatch => {
   // ...
   axios(...).then(dispatch(data => fetchCompaniesSuccess(data)))
}
```

In your `company_reducers.js`,

```
// Company Reducer Function, State here represents only the companies part of the store
case FETCH_COMPANIES_SUCCESS:   // should match the the type returned by the action
    return [
       ...state,
       ...action.data
    ]
// other cases & default
```

**MAKE SURE** to add `redux-thunk` as a middleware in your `createStore`, read [Redux-Thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) doc for instructions.

then in you component:

```
componentDidMount(){
   this.props.fetchCompanies(this.state.token);
}
```

Once companies data is added to the redux store, your component will rerender and the `companies` array will be available in `props`
You don't need to have a duplicate `companies` array in the component state.

You may want to Watch [Dan Abramov introduction to redux](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux), it is a free course.

Comment: Please wait a moment. I just start focusing on `Redux-Thunk`.

Comment: I am having a new question raised here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47767231/how-to-add-redux-thunk-to-existing-store

Comment: Thank you very much. You provide the crucial puzzle to me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your [dispatch](https://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#dispatch) syntax is wrong. The parameter should be an object with type and payload.

```
  return instance
    .then(data=> store.dispatch({
        type: 'GET_COMPANIES_SUCCESS', 
        payload: data
    }));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. But `Redux-Thunk` solves complete my issue first.